# Nested tags in Mustache.php

Tags: nested, mustache.php

I am using Mustache for php to render my webpages. I have been playing around with the code in the dev-branch on [github](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/tree/dev) and found some interesting how-to's. I know for example that is it possible to load partials dynamically by defining a helper function for them. What I can't seem to find however is a way to do nesting tags like so:

```
{{article.{{page.name}}}}
```

Is this possible with the help of some kind of helper or higher-order function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lambdas to achieve something similar. Quoting from [Mustache.php's wiki](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags):

> When the value is callable — such as an anonymous function — the callable will be invoked and passed the block of text.

So, in your mustache template, the following:

```
{{#article_field}}{{page.name}}{{/article_field}}
```

With a View Class like this:

```
class View_Page {

    public $_article;

    public function article_field()
    {
        return function($string)
        {
            return $this->_article[$string];
        }
    }
}
```

Will output the `article` field whose name resides in the `page.name` property's value.

Head over to [Mustache.php's official wiki](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags) to read more about Lambdas and callables.